# Как лучше оформить это предложение?

Tags: грамотная-речь, запятые, грамматика, тире, цитата

-Виктор Сергеевич, у меня для вас документы.

-Спасибо, Анатолий, а кто передал?

-Да парень какой-то, он и не представился даже. "Виктора Сергеевича знаете?" - говорит. Ну я ему: "Это наш бухгалтер". А он мне дал эти документы. **Передай, говорит, из рук в руки.** Так что вот, держите.

Вот как лучше оформить **Передай, говорит, из рук в руки**? Так и оставить, как есть? Или лучше через цитату - "Передай, - говорит, - из рук в руки"?